# javaScript breadcrumb error

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the following snippet of JS work? The result should be true if the basket range is in between 150 and 180 AND the strings below are present in the breadcrumb.

```
 var basket = "174.56";
 var cat1 = /Schlaftherapie-Lösungen/.test($("li[class*='ph-
     breadcrumb':nth(2)]").text());
 var cat2 = /Schlaftherapiemasken/.test($("li[class*='ph-
     breadcrumb':nth(2)]").text());
     if (basket >= 150 && basket <= 180 && cat1 || cat2) {
     console.log("true");
     }
```

This is a question part of job interview. I couldnt get why dosent work anyone would be able to anwser ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the selectors inside cat1 and cat2.

1. The apostrophe is after the end of breadcrumb, but should be after the closing bracket.
2. nth, should be nth-child.

Try updating cat1 and cat2 to what is below:

```
var cat1 = /SchlaftherapieLösungen/.test($("li[class*='ph-breadcrumb:nth-child(2)']").text());

var cat2 = /Schlaftherapiemasken/.test($("li[class*='ph-breadcrumb:nth-child(2)']").text());
```